# Python Dockerfile gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image with python as base, but I get this error message `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found`. I've not been able to solve this problem even if many answers are available about this error message. I've also tried ubuntu as base and include python installation into it  but also failed.

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.6 as base

COPY requirements.txt .
ADD mydir  /mydir/workingdirectory
ADD tests /mydir/tests
ADD src /mydir/src

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg wget curl unzip --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-key add /mydir/src/keys/key.pub && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com.linux/chrome/deb stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update - y && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && \
    CHROMEVER=$(google-chrome --product-version | grep -o "[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*") && \
    DRIVERVER=$(curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROMEVER") && \
    wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$DRIVERVER/chromedriver_linux_64.zip" && \
    unzip /chromedriver/chromedriver* -d /chromedriver

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    apt-get install -y npm && \
    npm install -g -y appium && \
    npm install -g -y appium-doctor

ENV PATH /chromedriver:$PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH /mydir

WORKDIR /mydir/tests/
ENTRYPOINT ["robot", "-d", "/test-results", "-C", "off"]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Which step in the build process generates that error message?

Comment: This step: ```apt-get install -y gnupg wget curl unzip --no-install-recommends && \``` and I also noticed, that he tries to install debian package and not ubuntu, I don't know if it could be one more problem, but this docker file used to work 1 year ago...